# ldap filter issue with searching users

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I nave such hierarchy of my AD:

```
ou=webapp,ou=groups,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com
```

And in ou=admins I have CN-groups, such as `cn=g-backend`, `cn=g-frontend`, etc (`g` is a prefix group)

all users are contained in multiple OU in `ou=groups,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com`, for example `ou=admins`, `ou=office`, etc

I'm adding users to group cn=g-backend or cn=g-frontend, but in keycloak app I can't configure ldap filter to import users without specifiyng specific group, exmpl:

```
(|(memberof=cn=g-backend,ou=webapp,ou=groups,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com)
  (memberof=cn=g-backend,ou=webapp,ou=groups,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com))
```

But, is there any filter query to get all users from all cn-groups in ou, because I want to add more groups in ou=webapp in future and dont want to rewrite query?

I tried wildcards all kinds of
`(memberof=*)` or `(memberof=CN=*)` or `(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=g*))` and others - it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, LDAP does not support that kind of indirection. (And because memberOf is a DN-valued attribute, it usually does not support substring searches, either.) If you're limited to a single filter, then you will need a single group that all users are members of.

- Either make all users direct members of the master "g-all-keycloak-users" group (in addition to your existing groups of course),
- or add the *groups* to the parent "keycloak-users" group, then use the Active Directory-specific "chain match" operator which performs a recursive check:

  ```
  (memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=g-all-keycloak-users,OU=groups,etc,etc,etc)
  ```

  (In my experience with Samba 4.x's AD implementation, queries that use this operator were quite slow, so I hope that doesn't apply to Microsoft AD.)